# How to make the parent git folder always point to latest commit whenever there is a new commit in child module(submodule) - Any Alternative?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-commit

Every time I push a commit to the submodule I need to update the parent repo to the latest commit in the submodule. Is there any automatic way to do that in the remote?

I understood that there is no way directly I can achieve this, but cCan someone suggest an alternate for git submodules? I just saw git-tree, google repo tools but not sure how to change my current setup to use those?

Comment: Submodule Git repositories are generally not even aware that some superproject is using them. That makes it literally impossible: if my repo X on GitHub is your submodule, and I make new commits in my repo X, I'm not going to be alerting you to them.

Comment: @torek , that is correct but what alternate we can do on this one, my scenario I want to put infra related code in a separate repository and application code should be in another repository, but my application code should use my infra code (which is in different repo )

Comment: If you control both repos, there's no problem here: whenever you make a new commit in repo S (the submodule), make a new commit in repo R (the superproject). Write yourself a little script (or even a large one, whatever size it takes).

Comment: @torek , but there are nearly 15-20 applications code repositories that need to be updated every time if there is a change in my infra repository.

even if we write a script , where that script should execute????, how can we invoke the script?????

Currently I am manually updating all repo's whenever there is a change in infra repo.

Comment: OK, so you have a list of "repos that depend on S". Your script will read: `for R in <list of Rs>` or similar, depending on what language you use to write the script. Given that there are many <R>s, the script probably should maintain a mini-database or log file of which <R>s have been successfully updated, and which have yet to be updated.

Comment: Where should you put this script? Probably, the same place that you make updates to S and run `git push`. How should you run it? That's up to you. Git does not come with such a script, so you must write your own, and then you choose how it is to be used.

Answer (score 0):

You mention google repo tools. Here's a solution by `repo`.

Say you have two repositories, `parent.git` and `sub.git`, hosted in `https://hostingservice`. The expected folder structure is

```
parent/
├── .git
└── sub/
    └── .git
```

As `sub` is not a submodule of `parent`, you need to add it to `parent`'s .gitignore.

Create a repository to track repo manifests. Suppose it's `https://hostingservice/manifest.git`. Make a manifest `foo.xml` that organizes `parent.git` and `sub.git`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
    <remote fetch=".." name="origin"/>
    <default remote="origin"/>
    <project name="parent" path="parent" revision="release_v1.2" />
    <project name="sub" path="parent/sub" revision="release_v0.3" />
</manifest>
```

Add and commit `foo.xml` in `manifest.git` and suppose it's on branch `default`.

Now you can use `repo` to download `parent.git` and `sub.git`,

```
# initialize the current folder as a repo environment
repo init -u https://hostingservice/manifest.git -b default -m foo.xml

# clone the repositories and check out their revisions
repo sync -c -d
```

`repo init` clones `manifest.git` and checks out `default` into `.repo/manifests`.

`foo.xml` instructs `repo` to clone `parent.git` and checks out its branch `release_v1.2` into the folder `parent` under the current directory, and clone `sub.git` and checks out its branch `release_v0.3` into `parent/sub`.

`revision="release_v0.3"` means to always use the current head of `release_v0.3` whenever you re-run `repo init` and `repo sync` commands. Sometimes you may want a specific commit `8b6228f4e0f5b059a6d5d93ba9aed15089c4b324` reachable from `release_v0.3`, then use `revision="8b6228f4e0f5b059a6d5d93ba9aed15089c4b324" upstream="release_v0.3"` instead to get a fixed revision.

When needed you can add more repositories to `foo.xml`.

Comment: My repo's are hosted on bitbucket
.gitmodules structure is :
[submodule "infra/charts"]
 path = arch/chart
 url = https://bitbucket.xxxx.xxxxx/scmgmt/archdev/chart.git
 branch = develop.

Answer (score 0):

> Every time I push a commit to the submodule I need to update the parent repo to the latest commit in the submodule. Is there any automatic way to do that in the remote?

Automatic way to do that? Yes. "In the remote" depends on what's hosting the remote.

To do it *locally*, you can have a pre-push hook that checks whether the repo's being used as a vanilla-ish submodule (with the work tree nested directly inside the using project's work tree) and auto-updates that containing project, here's a sketch of that logic:

```bash
set -x
IFS=$'\n'  # just sidestep wordsplitting
toplevel=`git rev-parse --show-toplevel` || exit
if up=`git -C $toplevel/.. rev-parse --show-toplevel 2>&-`; then
        # we're checked out and nested inside another checkout
        sm_path=${toplevel#$up/}
        if uplink=`git -C $up rev-parse -q --verify :$sm_path`; then
                # and it's got an index entry for this checkout:
                # it's using us as a submodule. update its gitlink entry.
                git -C $up update-index --cacheinfo 160000,$(git rev-parse @),$sm_path
        fi
fi
```

And that's the hard part, auto-updating the containing project's checkout.

The problem here is, just exactly how sure are you that containing checkout is really the right one to update with the new submodule stuff, or that the new submodule stuff isn't an exploratory thing not intended for production use? I'm not saying this can't be done, I'm saying that any choices you make here are going to either sharply constrain the workflows you can safely use or dramatically complicate the code. To the point that it's probably easier to just pop a message in the pre-push reminding you that you might want to to add, commit and push the containing project too.

Comment: My repo's are hosted on bitbucket
.gitmodules structure is :
[submodule "infra/charts"]
 path = arch/chart
 url = https://bitbucket.xxxx.xxxxx/scmgmt/archdev/chart.git
 branch = develop

Comment: Then learn how to run hooks and discover submodule structure and so fortth on bitbucket-hosted repos or do it on your local ones and push the results as suggested.